# Aiming left and right while shooting projectile from main camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script set up so that I can shoot unlimited prefabs from the perspective of the camera, but the ball shoots dead straight... I am not sure if my script needs adjusted or if there is an inspector setting on the main camera that needs adjusted. Basically if my cursor is on the left side I want the ball to be shot in that direction rather than in the middle of the screen.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Person : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject projectilePrefab;
public Text countText;

private int count;
void OnGUI(){
    GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width/2,Screen.height/2, 10, 10), "");
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    count = 0;
    setCountText();

}

private void setCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Ammo Fired: " + count;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void LateUpdate()
{
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 2;
    float y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    float yClamped = transform.eulerAngles.x + y;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yClamped,
        transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);

    transform.RotateAround(new Vector3(0, 3, 0), Vector3.up, x);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2")) //Right click. use Fire1 for left click
    {
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, 
            transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        Rigidbody rb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * 500000);

        count++;
        setCountText();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
rb.AddRelativeForce(projectile.transform.forward * 500000);
```

Indeed, `projectile.transform.forward` will give you the forward direction of the projectile you just spawned whereas `Vector3.forward` gives you the forward direction of the world (it is basically just a shortcut to Vector3(0,0,1) )

Answer (score 2):

zach. You'll need to use the new prefab's forward position.

```
projectile.GetComponent<Transform>().forward
```

As opposed to using the editor/world forward position.

Comment: any idea why this scrip wont work in vuforia with an AR camera but it will in regular unity